# JavaScript Split array for leaflet map

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to split a record within an array and put it again in an array. Code is shown below.

```
<script>
        var infras= <?= json_encode($infras); ?>; //[["Red Beach Seawall","1.3582,172.9266"],["Buota Bridge","1.3901,173.1343"]];

        var myStr = infras[0]; // "Red Beach Seawall","1.3582,172.9266"
        var strArray = myStr.split(",");

        // Display array values on page
        for(var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++){
            document.write("<p>" + strArray[i] + "</p>");
        }
</script>
```

The outcome that I want is something like this.

**Red Beach Seawall**

**1.3582,172.9266**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you data is a string, you need to first parse it into json.

```js
var infras= '[["Red Beach Seawall","1.3582,172.9266"],["Buota Bridge","1.3901,173.1343"]]'; // assuem you data is a string

infras =  JSON.parse(infras);

infras.forEach( i => {

  document.write("<p>" + i[0] + "</p>");
  document.write("<p>" + i[1] + "</p>");
  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `myStr` is an array and not a string. You need to join it first.

Working code:

```js
   var infras= [["Red Beach Seawall","1.3582,172.9266"],["Buota Bridge","1.3901,173.1343"]];

var myStr = infras[0].join("|"); // "Red Beach Seawall|1.3582,172.9266"
var strArray = myStr.split("|");

// Display array values on page
 for(var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++){
      document.write("<p>" + strArray[i] + "</p>");
 }
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

And as HW Siew said, if your `infras` value is in JSON, then you need to run `JSON.parse` over it first to convert it into an array.